# Error al conectar a base de datos

Tags: python, pyodbc

tengo este problema al momento de correr mi codigo en python

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

La forma en que me conecto a la db es:

```
cnxn_str = ("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
            "Server=" + SERVER_NAME + ";"
            "Database=" + DATABASE_NAME + ";"
            "UID=" + USER_ID + ";"
            "PWD=" + PASSWORD + ";"
            "encrypt=no;")
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
```

El codigo fue desarrolado en windows pero al instalar las librerias en mac y correrlo genera el error mostrado al comienzo

Comment: Hasta donde entiendo, no existe un cliente nativo de SQL Server para mac. Podrías conectarte a través de ODBC, que [si tiene un driver para SQL Server en ese sistema operativo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: @jachguate ya lo descargué, sabes como lo puedo llamar desde el codigo?

Comment: Lo publiqué como respuesta, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde entiendo, no existe un cliente nativo de SQL Server para MacOS. Puedes conectarte a través de ODBC, que si tiene un driver para SQL Server disponible.

Según las [instrucciones para la instalación del driver ODBC para SQL Server para macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16), puedes hacerlo ejecutando los siguientes comandos:

```
bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
HOMEBREW_ACCEPT_EULA=Y brew install msodbcsql18 mssql-tools18
```

En la página de Microsoft hay una serie de recomendaciones y aclaraciones que considero importante que leas, por lo que te recomiendo [visitarla](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16).

Una vez hecho esto, debes ajustar tu cadena de conexión para hacer uso de este driver, por ejemplo:

```
driver = "{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}";
cnxn_str = ("Driver=" + driver + ";"
            "Server=" + SERVER_NAME + ";"
            "Database=" + DATABASE_NAME + ";"
            "UID=" + USER_ID + ";"
            "PWD=" + PASSWORD + ";"
            "encrypt=no;")
```

Utiliza las siguientes cadenas, según la versión del driver:

- ODBC Driver 18: `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`
- ODBC Driver 17: `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`
- ODBC Driver 13.1: `{ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server}`

Comment: Me da el error "pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")"

Comment: Las instrucciones para instalar el driver están en la página de Microsoft. Si no puede abrir la biblioteca, puede deberse a un tema de permisos o a que no está correctamente instalada.

Comment: @Jhon De hecho, estoy viendo la sección _Solución de problemas_ de esa página y me parece que cubre tu caso.

Comment: ya use estas opciones y no me funcionan

Comment: Para lo que a programación en python se refiere, creo que eso está fuera del alcance. Debes tener una instalación de ODBC funcional y mi recomendación funcionará. Entiendo que eso no resuelve tu problema, pero quizás eso sea una nueva pregunta. Mi sugerencia es que utilices las herramientas del propio ODBC para probar y diagnosticar la conexión. Una vez la hagas funcionar a ese nivel, lo dicho aquí te servirá. Un saludo.